# Constraint on standard deviation of counts always zero

Tags: cplex, constraint-programming, ilog, opl

I'm currently trying to solve a scheduling problem for a sports team. My decision variables are declared as:

```
dvar int plays[Games][0..1] in Teams;
```

Where `Games` is a range from `0..19` and `Teams` is a range from `0..9` in this specific case. This forms a 20 by 2 matrix which represents which teams are playing each game.

```
[
  [3, 7],
  [2, 4],
  [9, 1]
]
```

Is an example of a 3 game matrix which shows that Team 3 plays Team 7 in the first game, and then Team 2 vs Team 4, which concludes with Team 9 vs Team 1.

In my constraints, I'm trying to express that each team should play close to the same number of games. My attempt at expressing this constraint is as follows:

```
subject to {
    gameBalance:
    standardDeviation(all(t in Teams) count(all(g in Games, s in 0..1) plays[g][s], t)) < 1;
}
```

I believe this formulation to be sound - however, I feel like I'm running into some sort of undefined behaviour, as the constraint is not being satisfied even though CPLEX says it returns an "optimal" solution of `[18, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` for the 9 team case.

Calculating by hand, I obtain a standard deviation of `7.59`, which is clearly not less than one. To verify this, I put the following in the result data section of my model:

```
int playcounts[Teams] = all(t in Teams) count(all(g in Games, s in 0..1) plays[g][s], t);
float std = standardDeviation(all(t in Teams) count(all(g in Games, s in 0..1) plays[g][s], t));

execute {
    writeln("counts: " + playcounts);
    writeln("std: " + std);
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
// solution with objective 0
counts:  [18 18 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
std: 7.48331477
```

Which further confirms that something about the constraint I wrote is not correct. To further debug the situation, I used the following constraint instead:

```
standardDeviation(foo) < 1;
```

Where `foo` was declared to be an integer array of `[1, 100, 10000, 1000000, 100000000]` - which definitely does not have a standard deviation less than 1. As expected, this model was shown to be infeasible, which shows that the standard deviation works as expected, thus the problem must be in the way I build the array of counts. I then tried the following constraint:

```
standardDeviation(all(t in Teams) count(all(g in Games, s in 0..1) plays[g][s], t)) + 2.999999999 < 3;
```

My theory was that if the standard deviation was being processed as non-zero, then this should render the model infeasible. To my surprise, the model passed with the same trivial `[18, 18, 0, ...]` solution above. By changing `2.999...` to 3, the model was infeasible. Thus, I conclude that the standard deviation I calculate is evaluating to 0 in the constraint, yet it is being calculated correctly in the result data section after the search has concluded.

At this point I am confident that the problem stems from the way I calculate the array of counts ( `all(t in Teams) count(all(g in Games, s in 0..1) plays[g][s], t)` ), but the part I do not understand is why it works in the result data but not in the constraints (as shown by the `playcounts` print-out above).

Furthermore, the following constraint works perfectly fine:

```
// The total number of games played must be exactly 36
sum(t in Teams) count(all(g in Games, s in 0..1) plays[g][s], t) == 36;
```

Which leads me to believe that the problem lies with the `all(t in Teams)...` portion of the constraint. To test this theory, I used the following constraint:

```
// The number of games the first team plays must be exactly 18
(all(t in Teams) count(all(g in Games, s in 0..1) plays[g][s], t))[0] == 18;
```

In theory, this should be a redundant constraint, since the trivial solution being returned begins with `[18, 18, 0, ...]`. To my surprise, this created an infeasible model. Even with `== 0` instead of `== 18`, the model was still infeasible. Thus, I wanted to figure out what this number was evaluating to. To that end, I added the following decision variable:

```
dvar int a;
```

And changed the objective function to:

```
maximize a;
```

With the following constraint:

```
(all(t in Teams) count(all(g in Games, s in 0..1) plays[g][s], t))[0] == a;
```

Which resulted in a model that had an optimal solution. The solution had `a` set to `-9007199254740991`. The same result happens if I attempt to `minimize` this model.

If I attempt to constrain `a` to be non-negative, then CPLEX crashes with an `### UNEXPECTED ERROR`.

#### Ultimately, my questions are:

1. Am I violating some rule of OPL and using statements in a way I shouldn't be?
2. If yes to the above, is there a legal, valid way to express the constraint I am looking for?
3. If no to the above, then why does OPL fail to calculate the standard deviation in my constraint?